In Solidity, is division automatically unchecked?
I recently saw a Smart Contract with an unchecked division.
However, I thought division was automatically unchecked, as:

Biggest possible quotient = type(uint).max / 1 = type(uint).max (no overflow)
Smallest possible quotient = 0 / type(uint).max = 0 (no underflow)

So I searched, and found this:
Can division underflow or overflow in Solidity?
And I see how overflow/underflow is possible with signed integers.
But for unsigned integers, I don't see how it could ever be possible.
So I would assume that when dividing two unsigned integers, no check would be performed, and unchecked would save no gas.
But just to confirm, I made this Smart Contract:

So as it turns out, unchecked uint division is still cheaper than regular uint division.
So does this mean uint division in Solidity is not automatically unchecked?
And if it isn't, why?

The compiler by default with optimizations disabled doesn't try to optimize anything.


So does this mean uint division in Solidity is not automatically unchecked?

It is automatically unchecked, if you have the --via-ir optimizer enabled.
For a proper comparison, you should also be careful to isolate the unchecked block and ensure every other aspect of the comparison is identical. As a simple illustration, the 4 byte function selector for div(uint a, uint b) is 0xa391c15b while divUnchecked(uint a, uint b) is 0xf41b4969. While the function selector in this particular case may not result in any gas difference, the point is that the unchecked block is not the only thing that's different between the two functions.
To demonstrate, create a Checked.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

contract Division {
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 q; 
    q = a / b;
    return q;
  }
}

And an Unchecked.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

contract Division {
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 q;
    unchecked { q = a / b; }
    return q;
  }
}

Notice that everything is equal except for the unchecked block. Now, compile both of them with the --via-ir optimizer enabled:
$ solc --optimize --via-ir --no-cbor-metadata --bin ./Checked.sol                          

======= Checked.sol:Division =======
Binary:
60808060405234601357605e908160188239f35b5f80fdfe60808060405260043610156011575f80fd5b5f3560e01c63a391c15b146023575f80fd5b34605a576040366003190112605a57602435908115604657602091600435048152f35b634e487b7160e01b5f52601260045260245ffd5b5f80fd

$ solc --optimize --via-ir --no-cbor-metadata --bin ./Unchecked.sol

======= Unchecked.sol:Division =======
Binary:
60808060405234601357605e908160188239f35b5f80fdfe60808060405260043610156011575f80fd5b5f3560e01c63a391c15b146023575f80fd5b34605a576040366003190112605a57602435908115604657602091600435048152f35b634e487b7160e01b5f52601260045260245ffd5b5f80fd

Now, you can observe that both bytecodes are exactly identical - meaning there is no extra check happening.
